# Regex math with perfect end bracket's

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, brackets

Its my string

```
{10
     {-55
             {{55x}{55}*55}
             {2}{5}
        }{10}
     }
     {55}
```

I need to change the `{a}{b}` into `(a/b)` .But they contain's more no of `}` brackets.I need match respected bracket's

like below:

```
 (10 
     ((-55(55x/55)*55))
             /(2/5) 
         /10)
         /55)
```

***Snippet***

```js
var a = '{10{-55{{55x}{55}*55}{2}{5} }{10}}{55}';

console.log(a.replace(/{(.*)}{(.*)}(?!.*\1)/g, "($1/$2)"))
```

I am not good in regex can any one help mee..

Comment: Sure I can help you : don't use regex when you need a context-aware parser.

Comment: I have to agree with @Aaron, regular expressions are usually a bad idea for transforming recursive structures.

Comment: @thanks What 's that context-aware parser.?

Comment: @prasad: "Use the search, Luke!" ;-)

Comment: A context-aware parser is a tool which parses text while being aware of its context. For example, when reading your string, it will know if it is already inside a curly bracket or not. Or when reading an opening bracket, it will know if it follows a previous token and needs to add a `/`. There may be generic libraries that can be adapted to your use-case, or you can quite quickly code one yourself

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

- Replace all `}{` by `/`
- Then Replace all `{` by `(` and `}` by `)`

```js
var a = '{10{-55{{55x}{55}*55}{2}{5} }{10}}{55}';
var b = a.replace(/}{/g, "/");
b = b.replace(/{/g, "(");
b = b.replace(/}/g, ")");
console.log(b)
```

---

**Caveat**

As pointed out by @[Darren Sweeney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973552/darren-sweeney), output is not exactly the same output but in my understanding its a typo. If you notice closely, `{10{-55` should be parsed to `(10(-55` and not `(10((55`. Also this extra opening bracket `(` makes equation unbalanced.

```
Input: '{10{-55{{55x}{55}*55}{2}{5} }{10}}{55}'
Output: (10((55-(55x/55)*55))/(2/5)/10)/55)
//          ^
```